# How do I load the values from one array, into another array, without changing the memory address of the array receiving the new values?

Tags: javascript

If I do this:

```
a = []
b = [1, 2, 3]
a = b
```

`a` will then refer to `b`

I want to copy all of the values in `b` into `a` without changing any memory address/references.

Comment: There is no real guarantee that an object/array will retain its address

Answer (score 4):

You could push the values without changing the reference from `a` or `b`.

```
var a = [],
    b = [1, 2, 3];

a.push(...b);
```

Comment: why not just `a = [...b]`?

Comment: also `Object.assign(a, b)`

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly that will create a new array. I think OP wants to change `a` it in-place, although I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to populate `a` in-place, without ever discarding the initial array, then you can simply loop over `b` and add all the items in `a`:

```js
var a = []
var b = [1, 2, 3]

var firstA = a; //get a initial element


b.forEach(function(item) { 
  this.push(item)
}, a);// <-- pass `a` as the `this` context

console.log("`a` is unchanged", a === firstA);
console.log("`a` is not `b`", a !== b);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: what's the point in comparing `var firstA = a;`, `a === firstA` ? it's always a reference

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly to show that `a` hasn't been reassigned. Superfluous, I know but it doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

```
let a = b.map(x => x);
```

The `.map()` function will create a new array with values generated from the source elements via the passed-in callback function.

As noted in a comment

```
let a = b.slice();
```

is pretty much exactly the same.

Basically this saves you the step of

```
let a = [];
```

since one brand-new empty array is as good as another. However, if you *really* have your heart set on using the empty array explicitly initialized, you could use

```
b.forEach(x, i) { a[i] = x; });
```

Comment: why not just `a = b.slice()`?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly because I'm eating a very good sandwich and it's making me disoriented :)

Answer (score 0):

A= b.slice(). It will create a shadow copy of element without changing original one. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice